# Record video untill spefific time is reached

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, video-capture, picamera

I am trying to record a video using `camera.start_recording` from `picamera`package until a specific predefined time is reached.
I was trying to counter this problem using code similar to the following MWE.

```
import picamera
import time

time_to_record = 15

camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (1920, 1080)
camera.framerate = 24

end_time = time.time() + time_to_record
while time.time() <= end_time:
            camera.start_recording('Test.h264', format='h264')
            # Here is another functions that samples a value from a thermocouple and annotates it in the video
```

Because of the function mentioned in the comment I'm not able to use the method `camera.wait_recording()` from the `picamera` package.
The camera needs to run for a specific time so the loop has to stay.
When I run my code I get the following exception:

`camera.PiCameraAlreadyRecording`

which mentions that the Camera is already recording. I'm think that this is a problem comming from the while loop because the `camera.start_recording()` method is called multiple times.
I don't have an idea how I can avoid this problem without dropping the ability to record for a specific time. Maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot simply move `camera.start_recording` to the line before the while loop?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned the function that retrieves the values from the thermocouple also runs inside this loop and so to have a video that is as long as the measurement helps me to relate the temperature values to other measured data.

Comment: So leave that function alone and just start the recording right before the while loop. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: I don't think this will solve the problem. Inside the function the camera is also temperature controlled. So there is another if clause that starts the actual recording process when a critical temperature is reached. I'm currently thinking that maybe threading the different tasks will bring a solution. Because I therefore can control the different AiO's,

Comment: post your full code and I'd be happy to help. As it stands there's not enough info to come up with an optimal answer.